# Import Excel File using Async Function TypeScipt

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous

I am attempting to use the `xlsx` angular library to import an excel file into my page:

Using some guidance from the xlsx library documentation I made the following function:

```js
public async ParseExcelFile(excelFile)
{
//Set up empty Excel Array
let excelContents : Array<any> = [];
let error : any = null;
return new Promise<Object>((resolve, reject) =>
  {
    var file = document.getElementById(excelFile)
    const inputFile: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>(excelFile.target); 
    const fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = (event: any) => 
    {
      const binaryString: string = event.target.result;
      const workBook: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(binaryString, { type: 'binary', sheetStubs: true}); 
      /* sheetstubs true supposedly shows empty cells but isn't */

      const workSheetName: string = workBook.SheetNames[0];
      const workSheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = workBook.Sheets[workSheetName];

      excelContents = <aoa>(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workSheet, 
      {header: 1, blankrows: true })); 
    };
    fileReader.readAsBinaryString(inputFile.files[0]);
```

however, on uploading the file using an html input, I am met with the following error:

`Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'excelFile.target')`

I am having a little trouble identifying where the problem resides however, any guidance or help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple mistake.

The excelFile parameter you passed in is not an object. Did you mean to use the `file` variable you defined here?

`var file = document.getElementById(excelFile);`

Comment: hmmm you may be on the right track but target isn't a valid method on html elements apparently

Comment: I think you need to console.log(excelFile) and file and get an idea of exactly what you're dealing with and exactly what you want.

Comment: Yeah I’ve been tinkering around with it excelFile was logging undefined